# How to add UIButton in between two views without using storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift

I am unable to understand where to add subview so that the button can lie in middle of the existing views.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the section named ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Any Tried code or where have u added the two View (storyBoard or using code) ?

Comment: I am not using storyboard I am working on a project which uses only coding.In that there are two views both are connected to each other and I have to place a UIButton at the center of it.You can refer to youTube mobile app user's account Tab where upload button is connected at the center of the two views.

Answer (score 2):

This is work for me. (swift 4.0)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let yourView = self.view
    addButtonOnCentral(yourView!)
}

func addButtonOnCentral(_ view:UIView) {
    let btn = UIButton.init()
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(btn)

    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: btn, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal,
                                             toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20)

    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: btn, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal,
                                              toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 30)

    let xConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: btn, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    let yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: btn, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([widthConstraint, heightConstraint, xConstraint, yConstraint])
}
```

Comment: what is setupViewOnCentral?